# wireless Needs to be restarted while switching network

Tags: windows-8

i hav a dell laptop with win 8 loaded. when i access internet on my laptop at home it works fine, but as soon as i switch my wireless connectivity i.e when i access the internet at my office it does not catch the connectivity initially.But when i restart my laptop and every thing becomes normal and is accessible.
why does this happen is it related to the OS or wireless drivers. kindly guide.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than restart your laptop each time do the following:

Open up command prompt (hit the windows button and type 'cmd')
Type:
ipconfig /release (hit return)
ipconfig /renew (hit return)
ipconfig /flushdns (hit return)

Can almost garuntee that your connectivity issue will be sorted doing this.

Saves a lot of time too rather than restarting your laptop.

The other way could be disabling your wireless also

Comment: Sometimes it helps to deactivate the wifi adapter, then activating it again.